# Если нужно ждать завершения Thread, то это лучше делать в финализаторе или в Dispose ?

Tags: c#

У меня есть несколько классов которые создают в конструкторе Thread (запуск производится отдельном методе - Start). Необходимо что бы классы не уничтожались до завершения работы потоков (они не фоновые, достаточно быстро отрабатывают, и желательно дождаться их завершения, а не сразу убивать при завершении приложения).

В связи с этим вопрос, где выполнять ожидание завершения потока (.Join) - в финализаторе (или деструкторе) или Dispose ?

Comment: `Dispose` для неуправляемых ресурсов, `Finalize` - для управляемых. Кто подскажет к каким относятся потоки?

Comment: Я не нашел ответа на этот вопрос, потому и спрашиваю где лучше ждать отработки потока :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Логика неправильная - Dispose по майкрософтовским гаедлайнам **должен выполняться за минимально возможное время.** То есть выполнять какое-то ожидание завершения операции нужно в юзерском коде, а не в Dispose и, разумеется, не в финалайзере.

Отдельный аргумент против ожидания завершения потока в Dispose - сборщик мусора вполне себе имеет право (и даже разумно делать его таким) быть однопоточным. Соответственно, если вы лепите Wait в Dispose, то на время ожидания завершения потока **у вас саспендится сборка мусора, а это очень плохо.**

---

Проанализируйте ваш текущий код - наверняка есть способ инвертировать логику вашего приложения, чтобы работающие потоки не доходили до Dispose. Активнее оперируйте TaskPlanner'ами и сервисами ThreadFactory, введите Producer-Consumer. Хороших решений - масса.

Comment: можно посмотреть на эти гайдлайны?

Comment: @Spectre на английском -- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: 1. В гайдлайнах Microsoft нигде не написано про минимально возможное время выполнения Dispose. 2. Сборщик мусора не вызывает Dispose, он вызывает финализатор, а это разные вещи.

Answer (score 5):

Финализатор (деструктор) C# предназначен для освобождения неуправляемых ресурсов на случай, если пользователь не вызвал `Dispose()` и не освободил ресурсы там. Финализатор вызывается сборщиком мусора. Когда CLR запускает сбор мусора, все остальные потоки приостанавливаются. Поэтому, теоретически, вы получите deadlock, если будете ожидать другой поток в финализаторе. Вообще, финализатор не должен делать ничего больше, кроме освобождения неуправляемых ресурсов (указателей, handle'ов операционной системы).

С этой точки зрения ожидать завершение потока лучше в `Dispose()`, т.к. вы сами вызываете этот метод.

Comment: >Этот метод используется для закрытия или высвобождения неуправляемых ресурсов, таких как файлы, потоки и обработчики, занятые экземплярами классов, реализующих этот интерфейс. 

[IDisposable.Dispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx)

Comment: @Spectre, если следовать паттерну Disposable, метод Dispose() освобождает и управляемые и неуправляемые ресурсы.

Comment: управляемые ресурсы на то и управляемые, что их и GC почистит, но  программист в праве сделать это за него